# Divide a foreach loops of 23 entries into two divs

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

I have an array with 23 objects in them that I would like to loop through and generate checkboxes for a form. Using Laravel, I came up with this:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'panel/update/games', 'id' => 'ajax']) }}


    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">

            @foreach($data['stats'] as $stats => $stat)


                {{ Form::checkbox('stats', $stat->Field) }} {{ $stat->Field }} <br>


            @endforeach

        </div>

    </div>

{{ Form::button('Update Statistics', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-block', 'data-after' =>
'Updated Statistics|check']) }}


{{ Form::close() }}
```

This works well; it generates 23 different checkboxes however, I would like to divide these results into two columns using bootstrap 3's responsive grid. So the data should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="">
  </div>
 </div>
```

A `print_r` on `$data['stats']`:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Username
        [Type] => varchar(30)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => PRI
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Prestige
        [Type] => int(2)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 1
        [Extra] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Level
        [Type] => int(3)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 1
        [Extra] => 
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Experience
        [Type] => int(10)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Points
        [Type] => int(10)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Kills
        [Type] => int(10)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Deaths
        [Type] => int(10)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => TeamWins
        [Type] => int(10)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => TeamLosses
        [Type] => int(10)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Bonus
        [Type] => float
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 1
        [Extra] => 
    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => AchievementScore
        [Type] => int(10)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Demented
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 1
        [Extra] => 
    )

[12] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Volatile
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[13] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Undead
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[14] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Scavenger
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[15] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Divinity
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[16] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Withered
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[17] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Killswitch
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[18] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Precise
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[19] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Adept
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[20] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Utility
        [Type] => int(1)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 0
        [Extra] => 
    )

[21] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Class
        [Type] => varchar(15)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => warrior
        [Extra] => 
    )

[22] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Field] => Perk
        [Type] => varchar(15)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => demented
        [Extra] => 
    )
```

)

Comment: what does the array `$data['stats']` look like? is it `key=>value` or numerically indexed?

Comment: I supplied a print_r of it now

Comment: Ok well my answer will work fine, but as its numerically indexed you can use a regular for loop as well, ill add an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a counter variable and add the closing opening div tages when it reaches the correct number:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">

        <?php $count=0;?>

        @foreach($data['stats'] as $stats => $stat)


            {{ Form::checkbox('stats', $stat->Field) }} {{ $stat->Field }} <br>

            <?php if ($count == 11):?>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">

            <?php endif; $count++;?>

        @endforeach



    </div>

</div>
```

Or use a for loop:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['stats']); $i ++)

     {{ Form::checkbox('stats', $data['stats'][$i]->Field) }} {{ $data['stats'][$i]->Field }} <br>

    <?php if ($i == 11):?>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">

    <?php endif;?>

@endfor
```

Comment: Your updated example broke the loop in half, but did not add the second column

Comment: @davidxd333 Oops, forgot to add the count increment, see my edit (added `$count++`) or use the for loop

Comment: Thanks! I had a solution like this on my own but I just couldn't get that little bit to work. Thanks again.